# What's the correct way to pronounce "cerpatee" from Myst IV Revelation?

Tags: myst-4-revelation

In Myst IV Revelation, on the island of Haven you encounter the bones of a large creature that Achenar has killed, a "cerpatee".

What's the correct pronunciation for "cerpatee"?